# Submitting form_tag as ajax either gives UnknownFormat error or renders js as html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe form and I keep running into errors when I try to submit it with Ajax.

Full code down below, but the line I've been trying to adjust is the `form_tag` line. With this:

```
<%= form_tag(buy_path(@product.id), id:'payment-form', authenticity_token: true, remote: true) do %>
```

I get this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in UsersController#buy
ActionController::UnknownFormat

respond_to do |format|  <= HIGHLIGHTED
  format.js
end
```

But when I specify `js` format:

```
<%= form_tag(buy_path(@product.id, format: :js), id:'payment-form', authenticity_token: true, remote: true) do %>
```

The js file is just rendered as plain html. As in, the browser just prints the contents:

```
$("html").hide();
```

---

Here's my full code. When I remove the inline javascript, `buy.js.erb` is rendered as normal, so there appears to be something added with javascript that's making the browser unable to process the request as ajax.

**buy.html.erb**

```
<!-- The form. Fields are inserted into #card-element with JS -->
<%= form_tag(buy_path(@product.id), id:'payment-form', authenticity_token: true, remote: true) do %>
    <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
    </div>
  <button id="submit-card">Submit Payment</button>
  <div id="cancel-bid">Cancel</div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var stripe = Stripe('<%= key %>');
  var elements = stripe.elements();

  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the customer that there was an error.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

  function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
    // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

    // Submit the form
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

**users_controller/rb**

```
def buy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

**buy.js.erb**

```
$("html").hide();
```